# oracle query for fetching some data

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

There is a table name "EMPLOYEE" having fields `emp_id`, `emp_name`, `dateofjoining`, `address`, `salary`. Now I want a query to fetch that how many employees join the company per year and per month whose tenure in company is greater than average tenure of all employees.

Comment: Can you, please, show what have you tried and what was the problem?

Comment: i didn't try any query yet... n the problem i already mentioned above... @Guneli

Comment: Don't use the `mysql` tag for `Oracle` questions.

Comment: you could try with group by and the have clause

Comment: Please Have a look at: [How To Ask A Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: We're not here to do your programming for you. You should make an attempt, post what you tried, explain how it's failing to do what you want, and then we'll help you fix it.

Comment: @Barmar i m not asking specially you to do programming for me!!! I m jst asking a simple query... and if u dnt want to answer thn its btr not to rply...

Comment: It's not just that we don't want to answer. We're trying to keep the quality of the site high, by ensuring well written questions that are helpful to both the poster and future readers. Questions that show no effort, and have no code for us to help you fix, are not good questions.

Answer (score -1):

You should use group by and the having clause.
I didn 't try if this code, couse at the this moment i can't. But take it as input for the solution.

```
select count(*) from employee
group by year(dateofjoining), month(dateofjoining)
having salary > avg(salary)
```

Comment: This does not look like Oracle syntax.

Comment: I know, but first there was also a mysql tag in the question. See first comment from Barmar. And i also wrote that i did not try the code, but it was thought as an "input" for a solution.